Making a Loop function and table in R
*How can I change the following code to compute D for various values of r and display all D values corresponding to r in a table?
library(powerSurvEpi)
r=seq(from = 0, to = 1,by=0.1)
D <- numDEpi.default(power = 0.8,
theta = 5.05,
p = 0.44,
rho2 = r*r,
alpha = 0.05)]


df <- data.frame(r, D)?

@Seth, thanks, we need to read the value of r first and then calcualte D based on in

Hi elisa. The code in your question creates two objects. r is a vector of 11 numeric values. D is a vector of 11 numeric values calculated using the numDEpi function and the values for r. What else needs to be done?

Good time for you to start learning tidyverse functionalities, then
#load libraries
library(powerSurvEpi)
library(tidyverse)

# create a function that returns the D for a given r
foo = function(r){
  numDEpi.default(power = 0.8,
                  theta = 5.05,
                  p = 0.44,
                  rho2 = r*r,
                  alpha = 0.05)
}

# create a tibble with an r column containing different values for r
df = tibble(
r=seq(from = 0, to = 1,by=0.1)
)

# create a column D where it's values is the corresponding result from foo
df |>mutate(
  D = foo(r)
)


thanks so much for the help. Do you also have some idea about this new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78694094/loop-function-tidyverse
